# How was Solidity conceived and what design tradeoffs were made when building it?

Tags: solidity, history

Solidity is a new language designed specially for writing Ethereum smart-contracts. As compared with Serpent, which is an extension to Python semantics, Solidity is completely new and borrows semantics from other languages to be JavaScript-like.

What was the motivation for designing the language and features it should have and were any specific tradeoffs made during the process of building it?

Comment: I think you should post this question to reddit/r/ethereum as this is a question for the developers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's some explanation in the original design proposal here: https://t.co/An1ZpRSu7O .

Basically, it was meant to use some OOP features to provide a convenient abstraction for contracts. Objects' data could be arbitrarily complex through its `mapping` mechanism. The original design included the ability to specify (and therefore optimise) that mapping. For objects' functions, I leveraged the then-new Ethereum contract ABI specification to synthesise something familiar to OOP practitioners. The introduction of the `constant` function marker was also quite nice, since it allowed an optimised way of inspecting object state with Solidity logic.

It was meant to be a sophisticated tool for developing contracts that could ultimately give both developers and users good information on what the code did. To help this along, I devised NatSpec, a contract-friendly documentation format, and made that a first-class citizen in Solidity. I also proposed a formal proofing language subset (not yet implemented) in order to maximise the kinds of correctness guarantees that could be made.

I introduced events as a first class citizen into the Solidity language in order to provide a nice abstraction for `LOG`s similar in form to function calls. Inspiration for that came from the Qt meta-object system's "signals".

One later feature that Christian R. and I figured out together was function modifiers; that allows attributes placed as part of a function signature to make some modifications to the apparent function body. Being a very declarative means of expression, it's an idiom that falls nicely into the contract-oriented programming space.

Comment: ^just give him the damn bounty already. He's the creator of the language FFS.

Comment: @VoR0220 yeah, the system forces me to wait 24 hours. :-)

Comment: @Gav if you don't mind, you can [register](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/signup) your account to claim the bounty.