# Why was it necessary to develop Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am wondering why it was necessary to develop a whole new programming language for smart contracts. Stratis for example claims that C# can be used to write smart contracts. Couldn't Ethereum implement a compiler for any programming language? What is the advantage of Solidity over say C# etc?

Comment: If anyone feels that this question should be duped to the first link in my answer, please go ahead and flag. I was undecided :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Couldn't Ethereum implement a compiler for any programming language?

Yes. But it'd have to produce EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) bytecode.

With regards to the rest of your question, this should cover it: [How was Solidity conceived and what design tradeoffs were made when building it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-was-solidity-conceived-and-what-design-tradeoffs-were-made-when-building-it?rq=1)

Why invent the EVM? That's covered here: [What was the reason to invent the EVM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-was-the-reason-to-invent-the-evm?rq=1)